# VSCode launch configuration - View Generated Command

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to view the executed command that is run when you launch in vscode? I have a java launch configuration, and would like to see the actual command that is executed to run my program.

Comment: Doesn't it appear in the console?

Comment: my python execute commands always appear in the terminal, choose a different terminal in your launch config

Comment: @DaveNewton not for java

Comment: @A.Johnston Odd; it does for me. `[Running] cd "/Users/david.newton/tech/lang/java/playground/" && javac Foo.java && java Foo` How are you running it?

Comment: What are the installed extensions for Java language in your VS Code?

Comment: Are you referring to [these](https://imgur.com/Epn80yY)?